# Multiple Mezzanine projects on same server with Nginx and Gunicorn: "server IP address could not be found"

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, mezzanine

I'm very new to deployment. I'm trying to deploy two Mezzanine 4.2.3 projects (they use Django 1.10.8 according to requirements.txt) on Ubuntu 16.04. I deployed the first one successfully with this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). I can access it via its domain name, say, `example.com`. I'm trying to get the other one accessible on either `food.example.com` or preferably `example.com/food` but the browser returns: "server IP address could not be found".

The nginx config for `example.com` at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name [SERVER IP ADDRESS] example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
    root /home/example;
}

    location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example/example.sock;
}
```

The nginx config for `food.example.com` at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/food`:

```
server {
    listen 81;
    server_name food.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
    root /home/food;
    }

    location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/food/food.sock;
    }
}
```

I tried to use `example.com/food` but nginx kept saying there're suspicious symbols in it. I don't know if that's one of the problems preventing the page from being displayed but I changed it to the subdomain `food` anyway to try and isolate the issue.

The gunicorn config file for `example.com` at `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn_example.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/example
ExecStart=/home/example/env_example/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/example/example.sock example.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The gunicorn config file for `food.example.com` at `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn_food.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/food
ExecStart=/home/food/env_food/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/food/food.sock food.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx log shows no errors.

`systemctl status` for nginx, `gunicorn_example`, and `gunicorn_food` seem to indicate everything's fine. `nginx -t` says `nginx.conf` syntax and test are ok.

Both `gunicorn_example` and `gunicorn_food.service` are running.

Both `example.sock` and `food.sock` were successfully generated.

`ps aux | grep gunicorn` shows workers running.

Not sure if this is an important detail but I don't use supervisor or upstart for deployment.

I'm guessing I've written the urls wrong. But I've tried various combinations and haven't gotten it right.

`example.com`'s urls.py`in the same folder as`settings.py`:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url("^$", views.blog_post_list_index, name="home"),
]
```

`food.example.com`'s `urls.py` in the same folder as `settings.py`:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url("^food.example.com$", views.blog_post_list_index, name="home"),
    url("^food.example.com/", include('food_crud.urls')),
    url("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
]
```

The app's `urls.py` in the app directory:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url('add/$', food_crud_views.FoodCreateView.as_view(), name='food add'),
    url('list/$', food_crud_views.FoodListView.as_view(), name='food list'),
    url('(?P<pk>\d+)/$', food_crud_views.FoodDetailView.as_view(), name='food detail'),
    url('(?P<pk>\d+)/update$', food_crud_views.FoodUpdateView.as_view(), name='food update'),
    url('(?P<pk>\d+)/delete$', food_crud_views.FoodDeleteView.as_view(), name='food delete'),
]
```

What have I missed?

Edit 18 Feb 2018: `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` contains only `["example.com/food,"]`.

Comment: Next site "food" you put on 81 port. Try to open example.com:81/food

Comment: @Denis going to `example.com:81/food` just times out: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up more, asking on IRC, and experimenting some more, it turns out the only thing I had to do was to make both projects listen on port 80.

This puzzles me because most articles I read say to have them listen on different ports. Going to have to investigate more in this direction.